# ARP announcement when nobody listening?

Tags: arp

I have a system of three components which are, one switch, and two network nodes. Additionally I added a laptop (incl. wireshark) to one switch port to which I mirrored all traffic (ingress, egress) of the port where node_01 is connected.

The system is designed to be powered up at the same time, but the switch is the slowest component booting up. When the switch eventually is up and running I see in wireshark (picture below) that node_01 is sending ARP requests with source:destination `MAC_node_01 : Broadcast` and Info `Who has <ip_of_node_02>? Tell <ip_of_node_01>`. But nothing replies.

[image: node_01 sends only ARP requests without anything answering, broken case]

If I reboot node_01 (picture below) while the rest is up and running, I see a (1) proper ARP announcement for <ip_of_node_01> and a (2) `DHCP inform` from the node_01. Node_02 responds on that with a `DHCP ACK`.
The following ARP request (3) from node_01 asking for <ip_of_node_02> is now properly answered by node_02.

[image: trace when node_01 restarts, good case]

- I would like to learn what happens if an ARP announcement is not heard by anyone? How do other units react on messages from that node?
- Also, if this is the explanation for node_02 not answering on node_01's ARP requests, or if it has any other reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this is the explanation for node_02 not answering on node_01's ARP requests, or if it has any other reason?` the switch. It's the switch.

Comment: Thanks, if you read right the switch is up and running otherwise I could not take the traces (for both cases). Writing "it's the switch" doesn't help a lot. I want to learn why this situation occurs at all, what is the pre-requisite (considering the first condition) that ARP requests are being answered.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to learn what happens if an ARP announcement is not heard by anyone? How do other units react on messages from that node?

Normally, nothing special happens – other hosts don't care about ARP at all when receiving messages. They only need it in order to *send* packets to this node, and in that situation they'll do an explicit ARP query as is the normal procedure.

Announcements are not the primary way ARP works, they only serve secondary purposes: such as preemptively updating ARP caches in case the same IP address has changed to a new MAC (e.g. after some kind of HA failover) or letting Ethernet switches re-learn the MAC-to-physical-port mappings in case the same MAC address has moved (although any frame from the MAC will suffice, not necessarily an ARP announcement).

> Also, if this is the explanation for node_02 not answering on node_01's ARP requests, or if it has any other reason?

Most likely, no, it should not be.

The reason might depend on what your capture would show on the node_02 side. Does it even *receive* the ARP request? And does it really refuse to reply, or is it that the reply is sent but doesn't make it to node_01? Refusing to answer ARP queries is not normal regardless of any announcements (unless the IP address was detected as duplicate, maybe).

Without knowing what the capture shows on both ends, however, I'd suspect the switch itself. (For that matter, does this system even need a switch? Two hosts can be directly connected without.)

Comment: Added wireshark traces to my upper question.